# Azure Function v2 queue trigger only takes in Json messages

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-queues, json-serialization

I have an azure function project with a queue trigger; the project is an azure function v2.

When I add messages to the queue that are not of type JSON, I get an exception inside the `JsonSerialization.cs` at the line `JObject parsed = JObject.Load(jsonReader);` .

The exception is: `Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException: 'Unexpected end when reading JSON. Path '', line 1, position 3.'`

The code then proceeds into the Queue trigger normally.

When running azure function v1, I did not run into this exception.

Could someone explain why does azure function v2 force you to have queue messages that are of type JSON? And is there a way to avoid going into the `JsonSerialization.cs` ??

Thank you!!

Comment: New version is released, have a try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a known issue and the [PR](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk/pull/1930) has been merged, the update will be available when next version of `Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Storage` is published by mid October. See [related comment](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk/issues/1889#issuecomment-425601847) from Azure team.

For now the workaround is to ignore this first chance exception as it doesn't cause real problem. Under Except when thrown from, check `Mircrosoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.dll`.

[image]

**Update**

It should be fixed since `Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Storage` v3.0.1